# How does Matlab Simbiology calculate pharmacokinetic (PK) non-compartmental (NCA) area under the curve (AUC)?

Tags: matlab, area, auc, extrapolation

I can't seem to find the answer to my question in SimBiology's documentation.

Does anyone know how Matlab calculates the non-compartmental AUC? Does it use the linear / log-linear trapezoidal rule? How many points does it use to extrapolate the curve to infinity? Does it use log or linear extension?

Many thanks!

Comment: The PKNCAAUC! That has to be easy. (just joking)